# Alternatives to ffmpeg as a cli tools for video still extraction?

Tags: python

I need to extract stills from video files. Currently I am using ffmpeg, but I am looking for a simpler tool and for a tool that my collegues can just install. No need to compile it from a svn checkout.

Any hints? A python interface would be nice.

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: Linux, BSD and Mac OS X at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements "cli tool" and "python interface" aren't entirely compatible.  Which do you want?

The following media libraries all have Python bindings: [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.org/), [libVLC](http://www.videolan.org/) ([pyvlc](http://code.google.com/p/pyvlc/) provides w32 binaries), [Xine](http://www.xine-project.org/) (via [Pyxine](http://pyxine.sourceforge.net/)).  I'm pretty sure none of them will be easier than using the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) command-line tools, though.

Regarding ffmpeg: why would more than one person need to compile from a svn checkout (or tarball, as they've recently had their [0.5](http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.5.tar.bz2) release)?  Grab or make a binary package and have everybody use it.

Comment: I completely missed the 0.5 release. Thanks!

You are correct - either I want a cli tool or a python library.